# Can the format of a Mysql table be maintained?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to keep the format of a `Mysql` table when the value of a field spans over 1 line? With long lines of data being entered into a field, the table seems to get messed up when I use the `SELECT *`to view the data. I have been wondering for a while now if this is possible?
Thanks

Comment: It seems you are getting problem in data format fetched by your query after exporting in excel etc. if it is then share your query and the row data where you are getting format issue

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql Terminal you can format the output as

```
select * from table \G
```